# ORA-02070 - When trying to delete record with text

Tags: mysql, oracle

ORA-02070: database MYSQL does not support some function in this context when deleting record

I have an Oracle 12c Db that contains all the data
I replicate some data over to the MYSQL db that only needs to contain temporary data every day.
I do achieve to insert with ease in the MYSQL from the Oracle db.

The issue comes in when I try to delete the records from the Oracle db on the MYSQL db as a job.
It seems that the issue sits with sending a TEXT field across as I can easily delete the same record using a number field.

My Oracle code that works looks as follow

```
  Delete "schemaName"."my_sql_tablename"@DBLINK
          Where "prim_code" = 114;
```

Now trying to use a text indicator

```
  Delete "schemaName"."my_sql_tablename"@DBLINK
          Where "text_ind" != 'N';
```

I get the above error
I can just assume that Oracle using the ODBC library sends it as a string that the MYSQL does not understand.

I have tried to send it in as a lexical or as '"Y"' or '''Y''' but non works.

Is there a specific method to send a text across as part of the where clause?

I get the same if I try to select a record with a text as part of the where clause

Regards

Comment: Please move your error message from the title into the question

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have any columns defined as NVARCHAR? If this is the case, then you'll get this error.

Add "CHARSET = utf8" to odbc.ini for your MySQL driver to resolve.  If you're on Windows, then its

Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Data Sources (ODBC), ODBC DataSource Adminstrator:

In the Systems DSN tab click on the MYSQL DSN and choose 'Configure',  expand 'Details',  choose 'Connection' tab,  in the 'Character Set' box add UTF8